# Select from the Form in a Controller not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a Form, I use React toolkit, but I have a problem, all my fields are updated when I change them it works correctly for me, with Https PUT, but when I have a select, it doesn't change it for me.

For the selected data I made a call to the API for the entity I wanted, and I displayed them in the dropbox.

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const categories = useSelector(selectCategories);
    const status = useSelector(selectStatus);
    const priority = useSelector(selectPriority);
    const methods = useFormContext();
    const { control, formState } = methods;
    const { errors } = formState;
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('all');
    const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState('all');
    const [selectedPriority, setSelectedPriority] = useState('all');
```

This is for set

```
    function handleSelectedStatus(event) {
    setSelectedStatus(event.target.value);
}
```

And here is Controller

```
    <Controller
            name="status.id"
            control={control}
            defaultValue={[]}
            value={selectedStatus}
            onChange={handleSelectedStatus}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                    value={selectedStatus}
                    onChange={handleSelectedStatus}
                    multiline
                    rows={5}
                    className="mt-8 mb-16 w-1/2"
                >
                    {status.map(categ => {
                        if (categ.id === field.value) {
                            return (
                                <MenuItem value="all">
                                    <em value={field.value}>{field.value} </em>
                                </MenuItem>
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                    {status.map(category => (
                        <MenuItem value={category.name} key={category.id}>
                            {category.name}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            )}
        />
```

Maybe someone else will consume it and this question will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Using Select.Option should work instead of using MenuItem.

```
 <Select
            value={selectedStatus}
            onChange={handleSelectedStatus}
            multiline
            rows={5}
            className="mt-8 mb-16 w-1/2"
        >
            {status.map(categ => {
                if (categ.id === field.value) {
                    return (
                        <Select.Option value={field.value}>
                            {field.value}
                        </Select.Option>
                    );
                }
            })}
        </Select>
```

Comment: The problem isn't that it doesn't render my component, it's that it doesn't match me between what I give it in the drop box and what it calls PUT

Comment: No because is very large.  But i can provide snap code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9n644f?file=Detail.js    The code doesn't render but that's how it works

Comment: My best bet is your categ.id is not equal not field.value in if (categ.id === field.value) {
                return (
                  <MenuItem value="all">
                    <em value={field.value}>{categ.name} </em>
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              }

Comment: He open in this function handleSelectStatus, but when I make the action the PUT from slice, Value from this controller, They not send value.

Comment: I musted used setValue() from  hooks Form, But now  not update